# How SQL's DISTINCT clause works?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, distinct

I'm looking for the answer on how DISTINCT clause works in SQL (SQL Server 2008 if that makes a difference) on a query with multiple tables joined?

I mean how the SQL engine handles the query with DISTINCT clause?

The reason I'm asking is that I was told by my far more experienced colleague that SQL applies DISTINCT to every field of every table. It seems unlikely for me, but I want to make sure....

For example having two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
u_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
u_name VARCHAR(30),
u_password VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE TABLE roles
(
r_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
r_name VARCHAR(30)
)

CREATE TABLE users_l_roles
(
u_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES users(u_id) ,
r_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES roles(r_id) 
)
```

And then having this query:

```
SELECT          u_name
FROM            users 
INNER JOIN      users_l_roles ON users.u_id = users_l_roles.u_id
INNER JOIN      roles ON users_l_roles.r_id = roles.r_id
```

Assuming there was user with two roles then the above query will return two records with the same user name.

But this query with distinct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u_name
FROM            users 
INNER JOIN      users_l_roles ON users.u_id = users_l_roles.u_id
INNER JOIN      roles ON users_l_roles.r_id = roles.r_id
```

will return only one user name.

The question is whether SQL will compare all the fields from all the  joined tables (u_id, u_name, u_password, r_id, r_name) or it will compare only named fields in the query (u_name) and distinct the results?

Comment: you shuold examine the explain plan for how your SQL engine decides to handle your syntax.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`DISTINCT` filters out duplicate values of your **returned** fields.

A really simplified way to look at it is:

- It builds your overall result set (including duplicates) based on your `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses
- It sorts that result set based on the fields you want to return
- It removes any duplicate values in those fields

It's semantically equivalent to a `GROUP BY` where all returned fields are in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I learned all this by making now, by making a mistake as shown here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750181/count-with-distinct  Finally, I ended up using GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT.

Answer (score 4):

`DISTINCT` simply de-duplicates the resultant recordset after all other query operations have been performed.  [This article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/20/sql-server-distinct-keyword-usage-and-common-discussion/) has more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First selects all the 'available records' and then it 'removes duplicate records' in all 'available records' and prints.