# COUNT with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I store all the shipping info for a customer in MyTable - CustomerId, ShippingID, ItemID, ShipDate. A shipment/shippingID can contain one or more Items/ItemIDs. A shipping id can have only one shipdate. Here is a sample of the table -

```
CustomerID, ShippingID, ItemID, ShipDate
C1, A1, I200, today
C1, A1, I88, today
C1, A2, I7, tomorrow
C1, B1, I955, yesterday
C2, B2.....et cetra
```

For a customerID, I want to display the distinct shippingIDs, number of items in a shippingID, ShipDate.

Expected output -

```
C1, A1, 2, today
C1, A2, 1, tomorrow
C1, B1, 1, yesterday
...etc
```

I tried -

```
select distinct shippingid, 
count(*) over() itemid, 
orderdate
from mytable
where customerID = 'C1'
```

Output -

```
C1, A1, 4, today
C1, A2, 4, tomorrow
```

Problem is that it counts all the items for C1. I want to count only the items in a shippingID of a customer. How do I do this ?

**EDIT - Right now, I don't need it for all customers. Just for one. So group by is not necessary.**

Thanks.

Comment: Aggregate functions need group by.

Comment: @Mihai Not necessarily, `COUNT(*) OVER()` would work just fine

Comment: A note on how distinct works - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/20/sql-server-distinct-keyword-usage-and-common-discussion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  shippingid,
        COUNT(*) Items,
        ShipDate 
FROM mytable
WHERE customerID = 'C1'
GROUP BY shippingid,
         ShipDate
```

Comment: What is the difference between count(*) and count(1) ?

Comment: @blasto none, it's the same

Comment: @blasto I don't see anything bad in your code, why are you saying that?

Comment: No, it seemed like I did a foolish thing. I should have figured out that only group by will work and not distinct.

Comment: @blasto Oh, yes, your query was using `DISTINCT` and `COUNT` the wrong way

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `Group By`? It's the easiest way... [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22b49/3/0)

```
SELECT
    CustomerID,
    ShippingID,
    count(1)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CustomerID, ShippingID
```

Comment: what is the meaning of count(1) ?

Comment: COUNT(\*) means count records. COUNT(column/expression) means count records where the column or expression is not null. Hence COUNT(1) means count records where the expression with the value 1 for each record is not null. Well, 1 is never null, so you count all records. It's another way of saying COUNT(*) and trusting that the dbms will optimize this such that it doesn't actually do the overhead work to create a virtual column on the fly just to count the ones :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
select customerID, shippingid, itemid, count(1)
from mytable
group by customerId, shippingid, itemid
```

Comment: Right now, I don't need it for all customers. Just for one. So group by is not necessary.