# SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, session, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to distinct the session number (which exists in the table as column `session`) but it doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know why?

```
SELECT DISTINCT session, sensor_1_2, sensor_2_2, sensor_1_2-sensor_2_2, recording_date_time
 FROM global_recording_in_sensors_vw WHERE song_name = 'Source1A_Dual_Comb_Left_44100';
```

This is what I get:
**As you can see- Double session**

```
session_867981022233244_**113** 24.10   19.10   5.00    2017-02-22 11:00:47
session_867981022233244_112 21.90   18.10   3.80    2017-02-21 18:04:43
session_867981022233244_**113** 22.40   18.80   3.60    2017-02-22 11:01:56
```

Comment: DISTINCT is applied to **all** the columns you select.

Comment: Please add example data and the result you expect

Comment: reading this may clarify your basic doubts; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992804/how-sqls-distinct-clause-works

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT (session, sensor_1_2, sensor_2_2, sensor_1_2-sensor_2_2, recording_date_time)
 FROM global_recording_in_sensors_vw WHERE song_name = 'Source1A_Dual_Comb_Left_44100' GROUP BY session;

Comment: I get an error #1241:

Comment: operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: I expect to have only this for example: 
session_867981022233244_**113** 24.10   19.10   5.00    2017-02-22 11:00:47
session_867981022233244_112 21.90   18.10   3.80    2017-02-21 18:04:43

Comment: I don't need to see the same session double.

Comment: Kindly, share the table structure. Thanks.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT session,sensor_1_2, sensor_2_2, sensor_1_2-sensor_2_2, recording_date_time FROM global_recording_in_sensors_vw WHERE song_name = 'Source1A_Dual_Comb_Left_44100' GROUP BY session;

Comment: did you check it?

Comment: Yes I checked it, it gives me back an error #1055..
And I don't know what you mean by 'share your table structure'.. can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: export the database, save it as a file, and share it. Got it?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT sensor_1_2, sensor_2_2, sensor_1_2-sensor_2_2, recording_date_time FROM global_recording_in_sensors_vw WHERE song_name = 'Source1A_Dual_Comb_Left_44100' GROUP BY session;

Comment: Kindly, give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Any luck?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
GROUP BY session
```

instead of distinct as distinct in query is applied to *all* columns

Comment: Where should I put it? in the begining or the end of my script?

Comment: SELECT  session, sensor_1_2, sensor_2_2, sensor_1_2-sensor_2_2, recording_date_time
 FROM global_recording_in_sensors_vw WHERE song_name = 'Source1A_Dual_Comb_Left_44100' group by session;