# Does DISTINCT multiple column is similar with CONCAT to make it unique?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, case-when

I want to understand the `DISTINCT` behavior between:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id, t1.surcharge_value) AS surcharge_case,
```

and

```
  COUNT(
    DISTINCT (
      CASE WHEN t1.surcharge_value != '0.00' THEN CONCAT(t1.id,"_",t1.surcharge_value) END
    )
  ) AS surcharge_case,
```

Does the first query use it's own `CONCAT` so it end up like this. For example: `id` is `1` and `surcharge_value` is `5.00`; so it become `15.00`?

If I remove underscore from second query; does it will `CONCAT` like the first query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How SQL's DISTINCT clause works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992804/how-sqls-distinct-clause-works)

Answer (score 0):

the first  count the distinct (not null) value for the tuple  t1.id, t1.surcharge_value

the second   count the distinct  (not null) value only if the condition   WHEN t1.surcharge_value != '0.00'  is TRUE because in this case return  a string
in others  case return null   and this value is not counted

in you sample  the first retunr 1  (distinct  1, 5.00)  meant numer of rows  with tuple not null
In second you are  check a string  and a number 5.00  != '0.00' 
in this case is always != and
 second return 1 because indipendently of the value the CONCAT(t1.id,"_",t1.surcharge_value)  is always NOT NULL

but for the value  (1, 5.00), ( 1, 0.00)

the first retur 2 and the second return 1

removing  "_"  produce the same result only if any value for surcharge_value is != from '0.00'